# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon in MOSS 2007

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I wonder if any of you might have any experience/suggestions/ideas in how to implement a ribbon control in MOSS 2007, that is identical to the version available in SP 2010

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, sounds like something I'd want to do...

I think my approach would be to utilize Javascript and JQuery to build out a ribbon and the associated buttons and sub-buttons.  Make them modular, small pieces of html, and store in a SharePoint list.  Then create a lookup list that has a url scheme and a lookup to that html library.  When rendering, have the JS ribbon determine which bits of html to show based on what is in that list for the given page's url.  Perhaps utilizing Regular Expressions.  Have a default ribbon as well.

A design issue that immediately comes to mind is, how could you design it so that the ribbon is smart enough to know that it is on a List page vs a Document library.  Otherwise, you'd have to have some url+ribbon html combination for every url scheme.